# Translate screen x/y position to react-native-maps coordinates

Tags: react-native-maps

Here is my scenario:

I have a react-native-maps map and over that I have a custom control that sits at the center of the screen (absolute positioning). The control is laid out (left to right) with a close button, marker and an accept button.

The desired effect is to allow the user to move the map to the position that the middle marker is at and click the accept button.

Note: the design is not to have a marker that he user drags around the map. I know that can be done with a MapView.Marker.

I question comes down to this:
Is there is way to translate a screens absolute x/y position to a map coordinate?

I know you can wire up an onPress event for the map. but the control is not on the map and the accept button is off to the right of the marker.

I’m running the following:
react-native: 0.40.0
react-native-maps: 0.13.0

I'm not seeing anything in the MapView docs and I'm wondering if I have to go native on this on.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Today, `MapView` component of `react-native-maps` module has a method which is called as [`coordinateForPoint`](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods).

I guess this resolves the issue.

An example of use (`x` and `y` as X and Y positions of the MapView): 
`this.map.coordinateForPoint({x:100, y: 200})
.then(coords => alert("lon: " + coords.longitude + ", lat: " + coords.latitude))
.catch(e => alert(e))`